# Expected Value proof

Tags: probability, integration

Here is the Lemma $2.1$ of chapter $5$ from Sheldon Ross probability book.   [link](https://pasteboard.co/GCe5xug.png)

For a nonnegative random variable $Y$ :
$$E[Y] = \int_0^\infty P\left \{ Y > y \right \}\,dy $$

They have used the following interchange of integrals. Please help to clarify this step !
$$ 
\int_0^\infty \int_y^\infty f_Y(x) \, dx\,dy = \int_0^\infty \left ( \int_0^x dy \right ) f_Y(x) \, dx
$$

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: by definition,
\begin{align}
P\{Y>y\}=\int^\infty_y f_Y(x)\ dx.
\end{align}
 Edit: I just wanted to clarify the answer that copper.hat post. The region $\{ (x, y) \mid y< x<\infty, 0<y<\infty\}=\{ (x, y) \mid 0<y<x, 0<x<\infty\}$.

Comment: yes, I got the idea of RHS but was unable to figure out the change of integral order. But by drawing 2D limits in a plane I got the notion of changing limits and order. Thanks !

Comment: It's a triangle.

Answer (score 1):

Try $P[Y>y] = \int_0^\infty 1_{(y,\infty)} (t) dP(t)$ and use Fubini.

Comment: Could you briefly explain how did you derive this? It seems basic but I can't get the grasp of it.

Comment: Jacky's answer has a slight elaboration, does that help?